# Finding origin of Pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

If you have an object1 and a pointer pointing to the object2, and we are currently in Object 2, then can we get from object2 to object1? How?

```
 (OBJECT1) --------> (OBJECT2)
                      we are here and we don't know where/what OBJECT1 is
```

Comment: Just give me your phone number and then you can call me. ;v)

Comment: If you 'had' `OBJECT1` and now you have `OBJECT2`, you had better just remember your previous pointer.  If you actually have a singly-linked list you could always build a temporary list or stack of pointers to help navigate.

Comment: This is reminiscent of the perpetual requests for a comefrom statement (for example, see http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ComeFrom)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Suppose you have several pointers pointing to OBJECT2

```
(POINTER1) ------------\
(POINTER2) -------------\
(POINTER3) --------------> (OBJECT2)
.....      -------------/
(POINTERN) ------------/
```

When you "go up", to which pointer should you go?

Comment: By the logic of the OP - why not the whole list? The answer is NO, and not because you can't point back, but because there's nothing to point to. The relations between the objects are in the program logic, not the programming language.

Answer (score 4):

There's no simple way to do so.  You can walk the entire address space, but there's no "reverse-lookup" in C

Comment: Even if you find the address of OBJECT2 somewhere in the address space, there is no way to know that it is a pointer and not some other data that just happends to have the same representation as the pointer address.

Answer (score 3):

No, you need to store the parent object pointer in object 2. For example, the Qt library do this a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Can't do it. You'd have to create a reference to object1 in object2 (doubly-linked vs. singly-linked lists are an example of this phenomenon).

Answer (score 1):

No, standard C/C++ pointers cannot be tracked back.

Actually, you could overload the `->` operator to set a reverse pointer somewhere, but it is better to ask yourself whether `Object 2` actually needs to point back to `Object 1`. 
If it does, storing a pointer from 2 to 1 is probably the best way to go.

To do so, and to be able to track multiple references, you could be led to write a referencing method in `Object2`'s class:

```
Class2 * Class2::getPointer(void * fromObject1) 
{
    ... add "from" to a table of Class2 that stores all the "Object 1"
}
```

A limitation of this being that nothing prevents an arbitrary `Object 1` to store a pointer to an instance of `Class2` (an "`object 2`") without declaring itself.

Another limitation being that `Class2` knows the "`object 1`" as `void *`. Unless you define a hierarchy of classes able to point to `Class2` and replace `void *` by it, having a collection of `void *` is not very valuable:

```
Class2 * Class2::getPointer(Class1 * fromObject1) 
{
    ... add "from" to a table of Class2 that stores all the "Object 1"
}
```

But here, only Class1 can use this system.

So the actual question is : what does `Object 2` need to do with `Object 1`? Why should it point back to it?

Answer (score 0):

In general: you can't. You can only do that if your object stores a pointer to its parent/sibling (example: double linked list, a tree with parent links) or there is an "resource-manager" that has some knowledge about these relationships.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is if object 2 has a pointer back to object 1.

On the other hand if you are say, writing a garbage collector you could take the address of object 2 and look through memory for that address you would now know where object1's pointer to object2 is.  This is the basic idea behind a conservative garbage collector. It would take a little more work and knowledge of how objects are laid out in memory to figure out where object 1 is.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to do that. Pointers in C and C++ are unidirectional and there is no central registry list of pointers that can be searched through (like it is done in a relational database).

To be able to get "back" you have to implement logic that maintains a backward pointer from OBJECT2 to OBJECT1 and updates it whenever OBJECT2 is pointed at by another OBJECT1. This of course only works if only one OBJECT1 can point to OBJECT2 at any time.